# How to transport text files python33

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

Technically, I'd like to have a mobile text file on my **flash drive**, which I refer to in a Python code in the same directory, e.g.:

`F:/Personal/Side-projects/Multiple Choice/userpass.txt # My code shares this folder's name`

The only problem is if I change my flash drive's directory (e.g. `F:/...` becomes `D:/...`) by *switching computers*, I wont be able to reference the text file I need, i.e.:

```
>>> with open("F:/.../userpass.txt") as a:
    b = a.readlines()
```

This will return a `FileNotFoundError`, saying that the `F:/` directory doesn't exist.

Is there any way I can bypass this?

Comment: if it is in the same directory why pass the full path?

Comment: I don't follow... @PadraicCunningham

Comment: You are saying your file is in the same folder as your script?

Comment: Yes @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Then don't pass the full path, if you need to change the cwd to the directory the  script is in then you can use os.chdir after getting the absolute path,  `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`, you can also use that to supply the path to your file with `open`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, you've lost me. could you just write the `open(...)` statement for me?

Comment: I added an answer with both approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in the same directory as the script, you can get the full path with the `os` module in particular [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)  and [os.path.realpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath):

```
import os
# get full path for script
pth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# join the path to your .txt file
with open(os.path.join(pth, "serpass.txt")) as a:
```

You could simply use the filename if you running the script from the same directory:

```
 with open("serpass.txt") as a:
```